# Gridview show only one row

Tags: java, android, list, gridview

I am using GridView to display a list but the grid return just one row .
How can I display all items in gridView?
My code :

```
            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/slide_item_rc_latest"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:numColumns="2"
                />
```

And my Adapter :

```
public class latestProductAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<SlideItem> slideItems;
    private Context mContext;
    public latestProductAdapter(Context c, List<SlideItem> slideItems) {
        mContext = c;
        this.slideItems = slideItems;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return slideItems.size();
    }
   ...

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolderItem viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slid_item, parent, false);
          ...
       }
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

In my activivty :

```
latestProductAdapter = new latestProductAdapter(getContext(), productListLatest);
LatestProductsGridView.setAdapter(latestProductAdapter);
```

Comment: print `slideItems.size()`

Comment: That displayed 5

Answer (score 0):

Most possible reason could be you might be using grid view inside scroll view.
So remove scroll view or use other xml file to declare.